# Multi AJAX image preview and button save to folder

Tags: jquery, ajax

im trying to use multi ajax to preview my image with a button to save image but it did not work.

(my photo-preview.php and save-photo.php are working fine when i did test with single ajax)

Update:

When i did follow @Andy Gee answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72507107/16910028

if use `$(this).data()` it did not work, if use `data` then it work but some time it get lastest image, some time it get the image before the lastest image. (for the first time or second time image select it ok but if i do many time with other images i see the problem as i said).

[image]

This is my full html and ajax code

https://jsfiddle.net/thutranabc/av8kfm27/12/

in photo-preview.php and save-photo.php i only use this to check the data.

```
print_r($_POST);
echo "<br>";
print_r($_FILES);
```

Thank you!

```
    $(document).on('change', 'input[type="file"]', function (event) { 
        var filename = $(this).val();
        if (filename == undefined || filename == ""){
        $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html('No file chosen');
        }
        else 
        { $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(event.target.files[0].name); }
    });

$(document).ready(function(){
do_ajax_submit()
$("#my_form input, #my_form textarea").keyup(do_ajax_submit);
$("#my_form select").change(do_ajax_submit);
$("#my_form input.my_photos").change(do_ajax_submit);

function do_ajax_submit() {
  var data = new FormData();

  //Form data
  var form_data = $('#my_form').serializeArray();
  $.each(form_data, function(key, input) {
    data.append(input.name, input.value);
  });

  //File data
  var file_data = $('input[name="my_images"]')[0].files;
  for (var i = 0; i < file_data.length; i++) {
    data.append("my_images[]", file_data[i]);
  }

  //Custom data
  data.append('key', 'value');

  $.ajax({
    url: "photo-preview.php",
    method: "post",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $('#preview').html(data);

      // Save the `data` somewhere for second ajax call.
      $('#btn_save').data(data);

    },
    error: function(e) {
      //error
    }
  });

  $("#btn_save").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "save-photo.php",
      method: "post",
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#save').html(data);
      },
      error: function(e) {
        //error
      }
    });

  });

}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to put the btn_save inside the first ajax handler, I would set a `data` of an element to the data you wish to pass on like so; If you only handle one image at a time the following will work. If you handle multiple images you might want to store the data in multiple elements then colelct it when the save button is clicked.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "photo-preview.php",
  method: "post",
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#previewimg').html(data);

    // Save the `data` somewhere for second ajax call.
    $('#btn_save').data(data);


  },
  error: function(e) {
    //error
  }
});


$("#btn_save").click(function() {
  
  var that = $(this);

  $.ajax({
    url: "save-photo.php",
    method: "post",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: $(this).data(),
    success: function(responsedata) {
      // Remove data for the next image
      that.removeData();
      console.log(responsedata);
      $('#msg').html("Image save successfully").fadeIn('slow');
    },
    error: function(e) {
      //error
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: hi, it does not work. If i use `data`  instead of `$(this).data()` then some time it save lastest image, some time it save the image before lastest image, some time save both of them .

Comment: Perhaps if you post more of the code I can help more effectively. For example, what event calls your ajax? If it a click event on an image maybe/ What's sent over ajax? What's returned.

Comment: Hi @Andy Gee  . I update my question with full html and ajax, php code.  Please help, Thank you!

Comment: My answer is also updated to help remove old values from your data.

Comment: Thank for your update @Andy Gee but i get blank data with your code. Can you make a test with it ?